# Laravel not reporting all exceptions to report method of Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel, exception, handler

I added a send email function to the report method of app/Exceptions/Handler.php

But some exceptions the method is called and others not, the `$dontReport` array is empty

[image: error not reported]

This error above, for example, is not being reported.

Here is the handler

```
    
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    public function report(Throwable $exception)
    {
        if ($this->shouldReport($exception)) {
            $this->sendEmail($exception);
        }
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    public function sendEmail(Throwable $exception)
    {
        try {
            $e = FlattenException::create($exception);
            $handler = new HtmlErrorRenderer(true);
            $css = $handler->getStylesheet();
            $content = $handler->getBody($e);
            
            \Mail::send('emails.exception', compact('css', 'content'), function ($message) {
                $message->to(['email@myemail.com'])
                    ->subject('Exception: ' . \Request::fullUrl());
            });
        } catch (Throwable $exception) {
            Log::error($exception);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us your Handler, please?

Comment: @thursday_dan ready, I added it in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel automatically filters out certain types of exceptions automatically.

> Behind the scenes, Laravel already ignores some types of errors for you, such as exceptions resulting from 404 HTTP "not found" errors or 419 HTTP responses generated by invalid CSRF tokens

Try updating your report method to this, this should send an email for every exception, regardless of the type.

[Link to the docs for reporting exceptions.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#reporting-exceptions)

```
public function report(Throwable $exception)
{
    $this->sendEmail($exception);

    parent::report($exception);
}
```